# Proving the 'pull out property of conditional expectation

Tags: probability

Can someone please help me prove the following:

For discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same sample space,

$$
E(Yg(X)|X = x) = g(X)E(Y|X = x).
$$

I read that since we are conditioning on $\{X=x\}$, $g(X)$ is a constant, so it can be pulled out, but I don't think this is a proof.

What I got so far:

$g(X)E(Y|X = x) = g(X)$ summation over $y \, ( yP(Y=y | X = x) )$

$E(Yg(X)|X = x) =$ summation over $y \,( yg(x)P({X=x},{Y=y} | X=x) )$

I am quite confused.

Are the two lines above correct? Is $P(\{X=x\},\{Y=y\} | X=x) = P(Y=y | X = x)$ ?

The summations are over y, so we can pull out $g(x)$ but we want $g(X)$, or are they really the same thing?

Sorry, I don't know LaTex.

Comment: Actually, the summations may have to be over both x and y.

Comment: My book defined what E(X|Y) is but didn't define what E(f(X,Y)|Y) is, so I am not quite sure, I assumed it is the summation over x and y of f(x,y)P(X=x,Y=y | Y=y)...

Comment: You don't need a separate definition for $E(f(X,Y)|Y)$.  $f(X,Y)$ is a random variable: call it $Z$ if you wish.  Then use the definition for $E(Z|Y)$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition of conditional expectation (discrete case)

$$ E[Y g(X)| X = x] = \dfrac{\sum_z z P(Y g(X) = z, X = x)}{P(X=x)} $$
where the sum is over all possible values of $Y g(X)$, and we're assuming $P(X=x) \ne 0$.
Since we are requiring $X = x$, only the possible values when $X = x$ need to be
considered, and these are $y g(x)$ where $y$ is a possible value of $Y$.
If $g(x)$ happens to be $0$, then $z = 0$ is the only possible value and the sum
is $0$.  So in this case $E[Y g(X)|X=x] = 0 = g(x) E[Y|X=x]$.  Otherwise,
  $P(Y g(X) = y g(x), X = x) = P(Y = y, X=x)$, so

$$   \eqalign{\dfrac{\sum_z z P(Y g(X) = z, X = x)}{P(X=x)} &= \dfrac{\sum_y y g(x) P(Y = y, X = x)}{P(X=x)}\cr
&= g(x) \dfrac{\sum_y y P(Y = y, X = x)}{P(X=x)} \cr
&=  g(x) E(Y|X=x)}$$

Actually, there is a bit of a caveat: we need
to assume $E(Y|X=x)$ **exists**, otherwise the right side $g(x) E[Y|X=x]$ 
is undefined.  Of course if $g(x) \ne 0$ the left side would also
be undefined, but in the case $g(X) = 0$ (where  we don't want to assign a value to $0 \times undefined$) the left side would be $0$.

Comment: I think I understand most of this, but I have a very stupid question. Why is g(x)E(Y|X=x) the same as g(X)E(Y|X=x) ?

Comment: It isn't.  $g(X) E(Y|X=x)$ is a random variable, $g(x) E(Y|X=x)$ is a number.  The correct statement is that
$E(g(X) Y|X = x) = g(x) E(Y|X=x)$.

Comment: Whoever asked you to prove $E(g(X) Y|X = x) = g(X) E(Y|X=x)$ made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Everything makes sense now. The original question was to prove that E(g(X)Y|X)=g(X)E(Y|X). I have now just realised that E(Y|X=x) is a function of x (a number, not a random variable) and E(Y|X) is notation for a random variable. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why can we say $P(Y g(X) = y g(x), X = x) = P(Y = y, X=x)$?