# For random variables $X,Y$ how to formally show that $Var(X+Y|Y) = Var(X|Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For random variables $X,Y$ I am trying to formally show that:

$$
Var(X+Y|Y) = Var(X|Y)
$$

I understand the intuition as if we know $Y$ (which is the conditional part), then any measurable function of $Y$, or $Y$ itself should be treated as a constant, which I believe is why the $Y$ drops out. However, the conditional part is a bit awkward and it seems like there is almost some sort of linearity at play, which is definitely not the case if $X,Y$ are dependent. Is there a formal proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\newcommand{Var}{\mathrm{Var}\,}
\newcommand{E}{\mathbb{E}}
\Var(X+Y|Y)&=&\E(X^2+2XY+Y^2\mid Y) - [\E(X+Y\mid Y)]^2\\
&=&\E(X^2\mid Y)+2\E(XY\mid Y)+\E(Y^2\mid Y)-[\E(X\mid Y)+E[Y\mid Y)]^2\\
&=&\E(X^2\mid Y)+2\E(XY\mid Y)+Y^2-[\E(X\mid Y)+Y]^2\\
&=&\E(X^2\mid Y)+2\E(XY\mid Y)+Y^2-[\E(X\mid Y)]^2-Y^2-2Y\E(X\mid Y)\\
&=&\E(X^2\mid Y)+2\E(XY\mid Y)-[\E(X\mid Y)]^2-2Y\E(X\mid Y),\\
\\
\Var(X\mid Y)&=&\E(X^2\mid Y)-[\E(X\mid Y)]^2,
\end{eqnarray*}
so it comes down to
$$\E(XY\mid Y)=Y\E(X\mid Y).$$
And that's ["taking out what is known"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018953/proving-the-pull-out-property-of-conditional-expectation).